# add elements of two arrays - the best way

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a = "1:2:3:4";
var b = "0:1:5:2";
```

I want at the end:

```
var c = "1:3:8:6";
```

meaning, the numbers are summed by column.

my solution is:

```
var i, k;
var a_arr = a.split(':');
var b_arr = b.split(':');
for (i=0;i<a_arr.length;i++){
   and here again another loop over b_arr
}
```

eeh ok, I dont have solution.. what is the cutest way to do this?

Comment: On the assumption that the arrays are the same length, why do you need a second loop?  You can use `i` to index both `a_arr` and `b_arr`

Comment: `c.push(+a_arr[i] + +b_arr[i]);` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just map it and return the added values ?

```js
var a = "1:2:3:4";
var b = "0:1:5:2";
    
var c = a.split(':').map(function(x, i) {
    return (+x) + (+b.split(':')[i]);
}).join(':');

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + c + '</pre>';
```

or splitting outside the map

```
var c = (function(y) {
    return a.split(':').map(function(x, i) {
        return (+x) + (+y[i]);
    }).join(':')
})(b.split(':'));
```

Comment: If this were a huge array, would there be much of a performance benefit to splitting `b` outside of the mapping callback?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I guess ya

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Yes, a pretty big one actually, I just did it inside to be more 1337 !

Comment: @adeneo Fair enough :)

Comment: @adeneo Haha, nice take on splitting outside of the callback :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Thanks, I always try to make simple stuff look really complicated, [it's a gift ....... *and* a curse](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/bb/bb43fa6b17052e3f8ea903b4f1b95168fb70a4fdb455c030291cecbab1f2836b.jpg)  !

Comment: If you don't mind a little `this` abuse, you can do the split without the IIFE and without creating a variable. `var c = a.split(':').map(function(x, i) {
    return (+x) + (+this[i]);
}, b.split(':')).join(':');`

Comment: Oh... and your `.stringify()` is stringifying a string. It just ain't gonna get any more stringy. :-)

Comment: @LyeFish - duh, I've just gotten so used to using that stringify and pre tags when using the built in code editor thingy, thanks, and cool fix using the `thisArg` of map for the second array

Answer (score 5):

Building on my comment, you can use `i` to index both the arrays:

```
var i, k;
var a_arr = a.split(':');
var b_arr = b.split(':');
var c_arr = [];
for (i=0;i<a_arr.length;i++){
    c_arr.push(parseInt(a_arr[i], 10) + parseInt(b_arr[i], 10));
}

//And use join to get the final result
var c = c_arr.join(":");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use index `i` to add the simply use `join()`

```js
var a = "1:2:3:4";
var b = "0:1:5:2";
var c = [];
var i, k;
var a_arr = a.split(':');
var b_arr = b.split(':');
for (i=0;i<a_arr.length;i++){
   c[i] = parseInt(a_arr[i], 10) + parseInt(b_arr[i], 10);  //Add using index
}
console.log(c.join(':')); //Use Join
```

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/fLavfcjz/1/

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and don't forget [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) otherwise the numbers will considered as strings.

```
var a = "1:2:3:4";
var b = "0:1:5:2";

var arrayA = a.split(':');
var arrayB = b.split(':');

var combinedArr = arrayA.map(function (v, i) {
    return parseInt(v,10) + parseInt(arrayB[i],10); // or return (+v) + (+arrayB[i]);
});

console.log(combinedArr.join(':')); //1:3:8:6
```

Comment: Worth noting that [the recommendation is to continue using the radix parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) when using `parseInt` for the time being.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - agreed

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var a = "1:2:3:4";
var b = "0:1:5:2";

var a_arr = a.split(':');
var b_arr = b.split(':');

var c_arr = [];

for (i in a_arr) {
    var to_add = 0;
    if (b_arr[i] != undefined) to_add = b_arr[i];

    c_arr[i] = a_arr[i] + to_add;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a second loop. The resulting array of the following snippet will have the length of the shorter input array.

```
var a = '1:2:3:4'
var b = '0:1:5:2'

var aArray = a.split(':')
var bArray = b.split(':')
var result = []

for (
  var i = 0, aLength = aArray.length, bLength = bArray.length;
  i < aLength && i < bLength;
  i++
) {
  result.push(Number(a[i]) + Number(b[i]))
}

result = result.join(':')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: You will end up with concatenated strings